# Pandas DataFrame: How to merge left with a second DataFrame on a combination of index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to **merge** two dataframes.

I want to **merge on** one column, that is the **index** of the second DataFrame and
one column, that is a **column** in the second Dataframe. The column/index names are different in both DataFrames.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(i,'ABCDEFGHJKL'[j], i*2 + j) 
                    for i in range(10) 
                    for j in range(10)],
                    columns = ['Index','Sub','Value']).set_index('Index')

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['SOMEKEY-A',0,'A','MORE'],
                    ['SOMEKEY-B',4,'C','MORE'],
                    ['SOMEKEY-C',7,'A','MORE'],
                    ['SOMEKEY-D',5,'Z','MORE']
                   ], columns=['key', 'Ext. Index', 'Ext. Sub', 'Description']
                  ).set_index('key')
```

df1 prints out

```
key Ext. Index  Ext. Sub    Description
SOMEKEY-A   0   A   MORE
SOMEKEY-B   4   C   MORE
SOMEKEY-C   7   A   MORE
SOMEKEY-D   5   Z   MORE
```

the first lines of df2 are

```
Index   Sub Value
0   A   0
0   B   1
0   C   2
0   D   3
0   E   4
```

I want to merge "Ext. Index" and "Ext. Sub" with DataFrame df2, where the index is "Index" and the column is "Sub"

The **expected result** is:

```
key Ext. Index  Ext. Sub    Description Ext. Value
SOMEKEY-A   0   A   MORE    0
SOMEKEY-B   4   C   MORE    10
SOMEKEY-C   7   A   MORE    14
SOMEKEY-D   5   Z   MORE    None
```

Manually, the merge works like this

```
def get_value(x):
    try:
        return df2[(df2.Sub == x['Ext. Sub']) & 
                   (df2.index == x['Ext. Index'])]['Value'].iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

df1['Ext. Value'] = df1.apply(get_value, axis = 1)
```

Can I do this with a `pd.merge` or `pd.concat` command, without
changing the df2 by turning the df2.index into a column?

Comment: I know you say you can't change the index of `df2`into a column, but can you change the index to include two columns?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require changing of indexes. I know how the merge on full indexes or sets of column work, I'm wondering, if changing is necessary, which is a memory problem on large datasets. Changing the index on df1 would be acceptable, but I'm hoping to do it without

Comment: how about looking with `pd.merge(df1,df2, on='Index')`

Comment: @pygo, the aim is to fill the ['Ext. Value'] column from df2, also in df1, the "Index" column for the merge is named "Ext. Index", so this would not help

Comment: try `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Ext. Index', 'Ext. Sub'], right_on=[df2.index, 'Sub']).set_index(df1.index)` ?

Comment: moved below answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
df_new = (df1.merge(df2[['Sub', 'Value']],
                    how='left',
                    left_on=['Ext. Index', 'Ext. Sub'],
                    right_on=[df2.index, 'Sub'])
          .set_index(df1.index)
          .drop('Sub', axis=1))
```

Comment: This works. I didn't know that you are allowed to use df2.index as a column name, I only had to filter the column names at the end to get the expected result. `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Ext. Index', 'Ext. Sub'], right_on=[df2.index, 'Sub']).set_index(df1.index)[list(df1.columns) + ['Value']]`. Thanks.